# How to read partitioned table from BigQuery to Spark dataframe (in PySpark)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table and it's partitioned by the default `_PARTITIONTIME`. I want to read one of its partitions to Spark dataframe (PySpark). However, the spark.read API doesn't seem to recognize the partition column. Below is the code (which doesn't work):

```
table = 'myProject.myDataset.table'

df = spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', table).load()

df_pt = df.filter("_PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2019-01-30')")
```

The partition is quite large so I'm not able to read as a pandas dataframe.

Thank you very much.

Comment: which column is using for partition in table? I think you should use it in filter

Comment: It's in the OP, the column is _PARTITIONTIME. The problem is that in BQ it's a hidden column, in the code above, the `df` can not recognize this column.

Answer (score 4):

Good question

I filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/50 to track this.

A work around today is the `filter` parameter to read

```
df = spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', table) \
  .option('filter', "_PARTITIONTIME = '2019-01-30'")).load()
```

should work today.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "$" operator: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

So, the table you'd be pulling from is "myProject.myDataset.table$20190130"

```
table = 'myProject.myDataset.table'
partition = '20190130'
df = spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', f'{table}${partition}').load()
```

Comment: I tried it before I posted this question, but it didn't work. A snippet of error message was: `Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: there was an error creating the session: table decorators are not supported in standard SQL`